# mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get my head around mysql.  Can someone tell my why this mysql query is not working? I am getting the following error:

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects
>   exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   /home/freebet2/public_html/test.php on
>   line 11

**test.php**

```
<?php
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/db.php');
        $conn = db_connect();
        $result = $conn->query("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN refer_old INT(10) AFTER refer_id");

              if(!$result){
                 echo "Error with MySQL Query: ".mysqli_error();
             }
        ?>
```

**db.php**

```
 <?php

    function db_connect() {
       $result = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
       if (!$result) {
         throw new Exception('Could not connect to database server');
       } else {
         return $result;
       }
    }

    ?>
```

If I change the alter string to something like : `$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users refer_id");` I get no error for some reason.

Comment: Hey Mike, welcome to SO. You don't have to put SOLVED in the title of your question after it has been resolved. Just mark the answer as correct (as you did) and you're done! Happy overflowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the sql error is concerned, does 'user' have permissions to alter the table?

Comment: As a matter of fact, no ALTER was not a priviledge set for user.  I have enabled this and the query does create the table but error message of mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean still appears

Comment: Lol, yeh the same error appeared and I assumed the query did not execute but I have just checked the table and it did in fact create it , I just didn't set the 'if' statements up correctly either. Thanks for solving the issue, i've been scratching my head for the past 4 hours!

Comment: @jeroen I stumbled on this question by Googling the same error message for a recent question here. So, that's what the issue with the OP was, huh? Right on. Glad to see that "you" were the one who figured out this mind boggler! ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Hmmmmm, pretty poor answer you managed to stumble upon. Ah well, that was a pretty long time ago as well :-)

Comment: @jeroen Yeah, oh well... you know how it goes. I'll use this Q&A for future possible duplicates including another that I have, just to cover all the bases ;-) This was quite the "Sherlock" answer/solution though. I'd of never thought about that in my lifetime, not in a milion years. *But!* ... maybe in my next lifetime, who knows. Maybe I'll come back as some form of guru master chef coder, *heh!* buongiorno, a presto!!

Answer (score 12):

You are mixing the object-oriented and the procedural styles of the mysqli API :

You are using object-oriented :

```
$result = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
```

And, then, procedural :

```
echo "Error with MySQL Query: ".mysqli_error();
```

You should use either OO, or procedural -- but not both ; and if you choose procedural, the functions expect the link identifier passed as a parameter.

For instance, [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/mysqli_error) should be called either using the object-oriented API :

```
$link = new mysqli(...);
echo $link->error;
```

Or the procedural API :

```
$link = mysqli_connect(...);
echo mysqli_error($link);
```

*(Of course, it will not change the fact that you are having an error in your SQL query, but it'll allow you to get the error message, which should help finding the cause of that error)*

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, yeh I've been picking code out from different PHP books and have missed the two up.

Answer (score 4):

Use `mysqli_error($result)` as mysqli_error expects the connection to be passed as a parameter.

Comment: Yep I replaced my code to use mysqli_error, which has helped.

Comment: This solved my problem. This answer should be the selected best answer.

Comment: Actually, the answer is confusing, as it used "$result" as an example. However, the text explains that "mysqli_error expects the CONNECTION to be passed as a parameter". So, given the original question example, it should be mysqli_error($conn);